# Need help to get check the value of radio button list checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, radiobuttonlist

`http://jsfiddle.net/EwKNW/2/`

I need to check whether the following radio buttonlist is checked yes or no.

I have tried with easier HTML structure its working fine (  `http://jsfiddle.net/pfZUt/6/`  )

I have trouble in using jquery and propagating through the HTML tree structure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to check for each couple of  radio buttons? Then just remove `return false`

Comment: I should able to know which option I have selected for the above HTML structure. I want to check it only to the specific last radiobutton in  the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your if else statements but you can get checked element names like this ,

```
 $('#myform').submit(function() {
        $('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
          alert( $(this).attr('name'));
        });
     });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfZUt/7/

You need to remove `this` from second selector because it's pointing to the `element_475` which tries to select inside it.

Comment: for this code http://jsfiddle.net/EwKNW/2/ whenever I click 'No' and submit it should give me an alert box saying that you have clicked 'No'. I have trouble in HTML tree propagation. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually an issue with your code.  The issue in the first fiddle that you posted is that you're not loading in the jQuery library under "Choose Framework", so the following code

```
$('#myform').submit(function() { ...
```

cannot be interpreted.  You can see that this is the case by (in Chrome) Right Click -> Inspect Element.  You'll see an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null".  This becomes fixed once you load the jQuery library, and the code you have works fine.

You can see the effects here: http://jsfiddle.net/EwKNW/3/